# I tried to reverse a string in a for loop, but it just isn't working

Tags: java, string, substring, reverse

```
    int num = 621126;
    String secondHalfReverse = "";
    String stringNum = "" + num;
    String firstHalfProduct = stringNum.substring(0, 3);
    String secondHalfProduct = stringNum.substring(3,6);

    System.out.println("the first half is " + firstHalfProduct + " and the second half is: " + secondHalfProduct);

    System.out.println(stringNum);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int right = 1;
        int left = 0;

        String letter = secondHalfProduct.substring(left,right);


        System.out.println(letter);


        left++;
        right++;




    }
```

The output I get for letter is:
1
1
1

Instead of:
1
2
6

I just don't understand why letter won't move up the string and select the other letters.

Answer (score 1):

because every time you loop, left and right get set back to 1. place them outside of your loop and it should work

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm such an idiot for not catching that.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the declarations for `int left` and `int right` above the for loop.

Their values are reset every time the loop is executed. If you move them out of the loop, this will not be the case and they will increment as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your loop like so, otherwise you `right`, and `left` variable will be set to `1` and `0` every loop.

```
int right = 1;
int left = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    String letter = secondHalfProduct.substring(left, right);
    System.out.println(letter);
    left++;
    right++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int right = 1;
    int left = 0;
```

are declared inside the for loop so are reset every iteration. Declare them before the for loop

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do it if you are willing not to use a for loop:

```
StringBuffer a=new StringBuffer("java hungry");
System.out.println(a.reverse());
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out.